# Is there a workaround to enable FILESTREAM in the code first approach of entity framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, blob, filestream

After much of googling I have come to three conclusion that until MVC 4 ( entity framework), that FILESTREAM (of Sql server) is not supported directly.

Is there a work around for the same?

Answer (score 3):

The best way for using FileStream Near Entity Framework Code first is things like this:
in your model has one field with byte[] type and in up method of migration write this code :

```
 DropColumn("dbo.Judges", "Photo");
 Sql("alter table [dbo].[Judges] add [PhotoTemp] varbinary(max) FILESTREAM not null");
 RenameColumn("dbo.Judges", "PhotoTemp", "Photo");
 Sql("alter table [dbo].[Judges] add constraint [DF_Judges_Photo] default(0x) for [Photo]");
```

Comment: I would hope that it is obvious to any readers, but just in case nb. this will delete any data that you have in that column!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, there is no equivalent of FILESTREAM in EF 6, that could be used with Code First approach. There is a workaround I found today, but haven't tried myself yet, though:

http://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/working-with-entity-framework-code.html

Basicaly, you need to use database first and create column of VARBINARY(max) type. Then tell EF to ignore it when auto-mapping and use custom sql query to read/write the content.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Great. Let us know how it goes when you try. I will try it out in the enhancement phase of the project I originally posted this for.