# Using file stream in in table with ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to using the file stream option in `SQL` server but I create my table in ASP core code first .

Fir using the filestream in table `SQL` , must be add the column in database

```
 CREATE TABLE TestTable
 (
      FileID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL UNIQUE DEFAULT(NEWID()),
      Pic     VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
 )
```

Now how can I create this column in the table with code first for use the filestream table  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a workaround to enable FILESTREAM in the code first approach of entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900028/is-there-a-workaround-to-enable-filestream-in-the-code-first-approach-of-entity)

Comment: https://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.com/2014/01/working-with-entity-framework-code.html

Comment: File Stream is currently not supported in EF Core, you ca track it here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4573